# then find the the radius of convergence of the following power series $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty}a_nx^n$ about $ x =0$?

Tags: power-series

let $a_n = \frac {(1+(-1)^n)}{2^n}  + \frac {(1 +(-1)^{n-1})}{3^n}$. then find the  the radius  of convergence  of the following  power series  $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty}a_nx^n$ about     $ x =0$?

My attempts :by Cauchy–Hadamard theorem  the  radius  of convergence  will be  1

Comment: The series converges for $|x|<2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write that
$$
a_{2n}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \text{and } a_{2n+1}=\frac{2}{3^n}$$
You can see that
$$
\frac{a_{2n+2}}{a_{2n}}=\frac{1}{2} \text{ and }\frac{a_{2n+3}}{a_{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{3}
$$
Hence the radius of convergence is equal to min$(R_1,R_2)=2$.

Comment: thanks a lots @Atmos